# Priority MUX - select one of the options based on previous value

Tags: fpga, vhdl, circuit-design

I have several workers that need to access single bus (memory channel). Several of them can be ready at the same time and I would like them to alternate with writers having priority.

I have some pseudo-code with two writers and two readers to showcase but it's not good solution and I need it to scale with arbitrary number of workers (writers and readers come in pairs). I also care about resource utilization.

```
if curr_worker = wr0 then
    curr_worker <= wr1 when w_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   wr0 when w_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   rd0 when r_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   rd1 when r_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   dummy;
else if curr_worker = rd0 then
    curr_worker <= wr0 when w_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   wr1 when w_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   rd1 when r_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   rd0 when r_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   dummy;
else
    curr_worker <= wr0 when w_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   wr1 when w_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   rd0 when r_rdy[0] = '1' else
                   rd1 when r_rdy[1] = '1' else
                   dummy;
end if;
```

And just to be sure, the when-else statement will assign the first option when the condition is true, even if the next condition is also true, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a round robin arbiter. They certainly exist, and with some careful coding it's possible to write a parametrizable one. For example, https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-axis/blob/master/rtl/arbiter.v is an arbiter I wrote some time ago that can operate in strict priority or in  round robin mode, with the number of inputs selectable at synthesis time with a parameter. This module uses this parametrizable priority encoder internally: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-axis/blob/master/rtl/priority_encoder.v .

Answer (score 1):

What you want is round robin servicing with write priority. For round robin you have to remember what happened before. Your code become something like this: (This is pseudo code for three channels)

```
if there_is_a_write then
   case previous_write
      when 0 => 
         if write1 then 
            select = 1 else
         if write2 then 
            select = 2 else
         select = 0;
      when 1 => 
         if write2 then 
            select = 2 else
         if write0 then 
            select = 0 else
         select = 1;
      when 2 => 
         if write0 then 
            select = 0 else
         if write1 then 
            select = 1 else
         select = 2;
   end case
else
if there_is_a_read then
   case previous_read
      when 0 => 
         if read1 then 
            select = 1 else
         if read2 then 
            select = 2 else
         select = 0;
      when 1 => 
         if read2 then 
            select = 2 else
         if read0 then 
            select = 0 else
         select = 1;
      when 2 => 
         if read0 then 
            select = 0 else
         if read1 then 
            select = 1 else
         select = 2;
  end case
```

You have to add code to remember the previous read and write.

You can make changes like having only a 'previous' without distinguishing between read or writes.